# Why do poweRlaw and fitdistrplus differ in fitted lognorm parameters

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution, power-law

I am trying to evaluate whether a power-law fit is appropriate for some data of lake areas that we have, and whether the theoretically supported alternative of the log-normal, at least at the tails, is more appropriate. We don't know what the minimum size cutoff is (i.e. xmin or area min), but we suspect that the log-normal generating process may only operate at the tails. We separately want to evaluate what the analytical distribution may be below the minimum. Here, we are only concerned with the tail behavior.

To compare the distributions I have been using the poweRlaw package in R, but also compared the lognormal fit from fitdistrplus (which is equivalent to MASS for this case) and have found different estimates of the parameters for the lognormal. My issue is that the meanlog parameter fit from poweRlaw is way way lower! Is it because it is fitting a lognormal centered as some value well below xmin so that the tails simply match, while the fitdistr package doesn't? This seems to be similar to fitting a truncated distribution but not sure. Some comments on the data - the areas have discrete values in units of 900 m^2 (i.e. 1 pixel), with a minimum value of 3600 m^2 (4 pix). Because the discrete values are so large (lakes with area 10^7 m^2 area), creating large discrete spaces at low values, I tried fitting to the actual pixel count. (i.e. 4, 5, 6, pixels).

UPDATE **
In response to Glen B's comment that this may be fitting a truncated lognormal distribution, I'd like to clarify that the exact question is why do poweRlaw and fitdistrplus differ in fitted lognorm parameters? 
**

Here is a working example (data available here: http://www.filedropper.com/lakes)

```
library(poweRlaw)
library(fitdistrplus)
# get data
lake_props <- read.csv("lakes.csv", header = T) ## 

# Fit powerlaw and find xmin:

m1 = conpl$new(lake_props[, "s.area"]/900)
m1$setXmin(estimate_xmin(m1))
m1$setPars(estimate_pars(m1))

> m1
Reference class object of class "conpl" 
Field "xmin": 
[1] 176
Field "pars": 
[1] 2.086846 
Field "no_pars": 
[1] 1

# Now to fit the lognormal to the same area as m1:
m2 = conlnorm$new(lake_props[, "s.area"]/900)
m2$setXmin(m1$getXmin())
m2$setPars(estimate_pars(m2))

> print(m2)
Reference class object of class "conlnorm" 
Field "xmin": 
[1] 176
Field "pars": 
[1] -0.4107272  2.6016914
Field "no_pars": 
[1] 2

## Now compare with the fitdistrplus estimate:
lake_norm <- fitdistrplus:::fitdist(lake_props[lake_props[, "s.area"] >=  m2$getXmin()*900, "s.area"]/900, "lnorm", 'mle')

> summary(lake_norm)
Fitting of the distribution ' lnorm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
         estimate Std. Error
meanlog 6.0905779 0.03792816
sdlog   0.8480994 0.02681909
Loglikelihood:  -3672.379   AIC:  7348.759   BIC:  7357.188 
Correlation matrix:
        meanlog sdlog
meanlog       1     0
sdlog         0     1
```

Comment: It looks like `poweRlaw` is fitting a truncated lognormal ($x_\text{min}$ is essentially acting a third parameter), while fitdistrplus is fitting an ordinary untruncated logormal.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify what I was actually asking. Is fitting a truncated log-normal, rather than a log-normal to the entire set of values above xmin, the correct way to go?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *fitting ... a log-normal to the entire set of values above xmin* that is distinct from a truncated lognormal? Do you mean a shifted lognormal, or do you mean to simply ignore the fact that the data had a threshold and treat it as if the data somehow just happened to have a large gap between 0 and the first observation? (I don't think that makes sense to do, but it occurs to me you might have intended it)

Comment: So, if I knew somehow that all lakes above a certain size (xmin) were produced by process A, and that this process resulted in a lognormal distribution, I would test my hypothesis by fitting a lognormal to those values. Here, instead, we truncate the left side and assume that our process operated on the entire range of values, but the sample contains no data from any values below xmin. What's the reasoning behind this? I may be misinterpreting the meaning or significance of xmin.

Comment: The claim "all lakes above a certain size (xmin) were produced by process A, and that this process resulted in a lognormal distribution" is literally not possible. The usual two parameter lognormal specifies non-zero density *all the way down to 0*. If you're not specifying that, you have to explain what you're doing that *is definitely different from a lognormal*